# Is it possible to maintain object-fit during a CSS transform?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm working on a component that transitions an image from a start position + scale to an end position + scale (i.e. to fill up the screen). This is done with a CSS transform animation on `translate` and `scale`.

The challenge is that some of the images to transition from may be altered by component users using the `object-fit` property. However, it appears that the `CSS translate` does not maintain the `object-fit` property during translate.

Codepen example here: https://codepen.io/cathyxz/pen/mXgEMB

I know I could technically animate `width` and `height`, but I want to keep in line with properties that browsers can [animate cheaply](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) for performance reasons, i.e. nothing that affects layout, which leaves us with only position, rotation, scale, opacity.

References: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Is there anyway I can gradually animate my transition to "uncrop" images instead of stretching them?

Comment: You’re wanting to affect layout, so no, not with `object-fit`.

Answer (score 3):

`object-fit` is applied to the element before transformation.

Whatever the outcome of all CSS on the object, `transform` takes it and applies the transformation. In fact, the element is left in DOM untouched. That's why `transform` does not trigger a repaint (and is considered performant). Only its rendering (the composite layer) is transformed. Its rendering is stretched 4 times on X axis because of the transform. But this does not make the element 4 times wider and therefore object-fit cannot apply as you expect.

---

Can you gradually uncrop? Yes, but not with `transform`. In order to do it as cheap as possible (without triggering a repaint on subsequent flow) you need:

1. A parent placeholder (with `position:relative`) as tall as your image, to keep the space free in document flow
2. The element to be animated, with `position:absolute`. Because of this, even if you animate `width`, you do not trigger `layout`, because the element is outside of document flow.

```css
.transform-placeholder {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.transform-placeholder .object-fit {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  animation: object-fit 2.1s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  
}

@keyframes object-fit {
  0% {
    width: 100px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="transform-placeholder">
  <div class="object-fit" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1600/400?image=857')">
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Animation above does not trigger repaint on any DOM element that's outside the animated div.</h2>
```